# Best way to process errors in all controller methods after validation in grails

Tags: validation, grails, groovy, controller

I have controller with number of methods, and use command objects for validate parameters. But for each method I must call hasError() and if it true process error(usually it means redirect to special page).

```groovy
class MyController{

    def action1(ActionCommandObject cmd){
        if(cmd.hasErrors()){
            //redirect to special page or throw an Exception
        }

        // do smth.

        render view:'/myview1', model: []
    }

    def action2(ActionCommandObject cmd){
        if(cmd.hasErrors()){
            //redirect to special page or throw an Exception
        }

        // do smth.

        render view:'/myview2', model: []
    }

    // More similar methods

}
```

**Is it possible to avoid process error case in each method?** I mean if validation fails then immediately do some code (e.g. throw Exception or redirect to error page)

I tried to make command object do something after validation but I cant because afterValidate method is missing(beforeValidate method exists)

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like [described here](http://refaktor.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/simple-trick-to-dry-your-grails.html):

```
class MyController{

    protected Object withCommandChecking( cmd, Closure closure ) {
        if(cmd.hasErrors()){
            //redirect to special page or throw an Exception
        }
        return closure.call()
    }

    def action1(ActionCommandObject cmd){
        withCommandChecking( cmd ) {
            // do smth.
            render view:'/myview1', model: []
        }
    }

    def action2(ActionCommandObject cmd){
        withCommandChecking( cmd ) {
            // do smth.
            render view:'/myview2', model: []
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still require call error process method in each action method. My main idea that action method shouldn't know anything about error process, if it has been called then all ok and params valid but if params invalid action method haven't be called (i.e. doesn't have code to process)

Comment: @AndrejSoroj [this might be an alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432514/how-to-access-command-objects-from-filter-and-is-it-possible-at-all) (using Filters)

Comment: Go through this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327091/how-to-handle-multiple-return-types-in-groovy-mehods